# ImageData to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to put image data onto the canvas c/ctx, here is my current code:

```
console.log('Worker said: '+ e.data[1]);
var image = ctx.createImageData(20,300);
image.data = e.data[1];
ctx.putImageData(image,e.data[0],0);
```

Yes, the worker is outputting the correct information (e.data[1] = image data array [r,g,b,transparency,...], e.data[0] = xpos to import)

I can't see why this is not working?

Here is my canvas setup just in case

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
var ctx = c.getContext('2d', { alpha: false });
c.width = 300;
c.height = 300;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign the array to the .data attribute, you must copy the values, this should work

```
var image = ctx.createImageData(20,300);
var length = e.data[1].length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    image.data[i] = e.data[1][i];
}
ctx.putImageData(image,e.data[0],0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers (all but IE), you can use the [`ImageData` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData), which accepts an *Uint8ClampedArray* as input.

So assuming your Worker sends an *Uint8Array*, all you'd do is to first create a new *Uint8ClampedArray* view over the same *ArrayBuffer* as the sent *TypedArray*, and then use that view to initialize the *ImageData*:

```js
const worker = new Worker( generateWorkerURL() );
worker.onmessage = (evt) => {
  // first a new view (same ArrayBuffer)
  const clampedView = new Uint8ClampedArray( evt.data.buffer );
  const imageData = new ImageData( clampedView, 500, 300 );
  const ctx = document.getElementById( 'canvas' ).getContext( '2d' );
  ctx.putImageData( imageData, 0, 0 );
};



// helper to integrate Worker in a Snippet
function generateWorkerURL() {
  const content = document.querySelector('[type="worker-script"]').textContent;
  const blob = new Blob( [ content ], { type: "text/javascript" }  );
  return URL.createObjectURL( blob );
}
```

```html
<script type="worker-script">
  // fake worker code, generates noise
  const data = Uint8Array.from(
    { length: 500 * 300 * 4 },
    () => Math.random() * 0xFF
  );
  // We 'transfer' the TypedArray's buffer so that it's not copied
  // by passing it in an Array as the second argument of postMessage
  postMessage( data, [ data.buffer ] );
</script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Now, you could even start working from an ImageData directly in the Worker thread, and transfer it to the main thread when it's done:

```js
const worker = new Worker( generateWorkerURL() );
worker.onmessage = (evt) => {
  const ctx = document.getElementById( 'canvas' ).getContext( '2d' );
  // put directly the imageData sent by the Worker
  ctx.putImageData( evt.data, 0, 0 );
};



// helper to integrate Worker in a Snippet
function generateWorkerURL() {
  const content = document.querySelector('[type="worker-script"]').textContent;
  const blob = new Blob( [ content ], { type: "text/javascript" }  );
  return URL.createObjectURL( blob );
}
```

```html
<script type="worker-script">
  // fake worker code, generates noise
  const imageData = new ImageData( 500, 300 );
  for( let i=0; i<imageData.data.length; i++ ) {
    imageData.data[ i ] = Math.random() * 0xFF;
  }
  // we transfer the ImageData's buffer
  postMessage( imageData, [ imageData.data.buffer ] );
</script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```